# Sharepoint Online: Are attachments also delete on deleting a ListItem?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-clientobject

Will the ListItem's attachments also be deleted if I call the `ListItem.DeleteObject` method which deletes my item? Or are the attachment files still on my server? How can I check this? I use the client object model!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, attachments associated with list item are getting deleted once the [`ListItem.DeleteObject` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.deleteobject.aspx) is invoked and the query is submitted to the server via [`ClientContext.ExecuteQuery` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.executequery.aspx).

The following example demonstrates how to verify whether attachments have been deleted:

```
//First, lets delete list item that contains attachments 
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
ctx.Load(list.RootFolder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
item.DeleteObject(); //delete list item operation
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//Then, let's verify whether associated attachment file(s) have been deleted  
var attachamentRootFolderUrl = string.Format("{0}/Attachments",list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
var attachamentFolderUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", attachamentRootFolderUrl, itemId);
var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(attachamentRootFolderUrl);
var result = ctx.LoadQuery(folder.Folders.Where( f => f.ServerRelativeUrl == attachamentFolderUrl));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (!result.Any())
{
     Console.WriteLine("Attachaments have been deleted.");
}
```